# I'm having trouble accessing midi files in a different folder

Tags: python, pygame, os.path

> My code, Vincible.py, is located in
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Vincible
> ```
>
> and I'm trying to access the midi files located in
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Vincible\Audio
> ```
>
> I've put together:
>
> ```
> #!C:\Python33\python.exe
> import sys, pygame, os.path
>
> print("Loading...")
> pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
> try:
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'title.midi'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun1.midi'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun2.midi'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun3.midi'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun4.midi'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun5.midi'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun6.midi'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'echostheme'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'town1.midi'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'town2.midi'))
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'town3.midi'))
> except:
>     raise UserWarning("Could not load or play soundfiles in 'Audio' folder")  
> pygame.init()
> size = width, height = 580, 444
> screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
> print("Loaded!")
>
> while 1:
>     for event in pygame.event.get():
>       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>           sys.exit()
>     pygame.mixer.Sound('title.midi').play()
> ```
>
> Upon running it, it runs the except bit and I'm struggling to figure
>   out how to successfully do this.  I don't typically work with
>   accessing files from different paths in Python, so your help is very
>   much appreciated.
>
> Edit:  As subtly requested, I removed the try/except from my code. 
>   Here is the new code:
>
> ```
> #!C:\Python33\python.exe
> import sys, pygame, os.path
>
> print("Loading...")
> pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
> pygame.init()
>
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'title.midi'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun1.midi'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun2.midi'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun3.midi'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun4.midi'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun5.midi'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'dun6.midi'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'echostheme'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'town1.midi'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'town2.midi'))
> pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'town3.midi'))
>
> size = width, height = 580, 444
> screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
> print("Loaded!")
>
> while 1:
>     for event in pygame.event.get():
>       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>           sys.exit()
>     pygame.mixer.Sound('title.midi').play()
> ```
>
> this time putting out:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Vincible\Vincible.py", line 8, in <module>
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('Audio', 'title.midi'))
> pygame.error: Couldn't open 'Audio\title.midi'
> ```
>
> The file isn't corrupt and it is indeed in
>
> ```
> Vincible\Audio
> ```
>
> but it's still returning this error.  I'd imagine it has something to
>   do with my use of
>
> ```
> os.path.join
> ```
>
> but then again, I'm new to the os.path module.  Any help is very much
>   appreciated.

As Fredrik recommended, I tried revising my code to this:

```
#!C:\Python33\python.exe
import sys, pygame, os.path

print("Loading...")
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.init()

def load(midi_file):
    module_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    filename = os.path.join(module_directory, 'Audio', midi_file)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(filename)

load("title.midi")

size = width, height = 580, 444
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
print("Loaded!")

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    titlemusic.play(-1)
```

Note: I took away all of the other .midi files to make the code smaller/more readable, after the issue has been resolved they'll be added in the correct manner.

When ran, the interpreter raises another pygame.error "The file couldn't be opened" on line 13 (where I load "title.midi").  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If only you didn't have that `except` in there, you could see what error is actually being generated... which would probably let you solve the problem on your own... or at the very least get us a lot closer to being able to help.

Comment: Right, sorry.  I'll try that and report any new results.

Comment: Puzzling.  So to check if this is pygame messing with you or something else going on here, I'd try adding `open(filename).read()` just before the pygame load call, to make sure the file is actually readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the folder when open the file if it is not in the same folder as your python file. May I suggest opening the files as `"Audio/file.midi"` instead of just the `"file.midi"`. That should work fine with out the function that was suggested by Fredrik. If you change where the files are stored (ie. you rename the folder or move the files) then don't forget to change it in the code.

EDIT: Also, a side note that is irrelevant to your problem but will help you out nicely on your project also, try getting the files dynamically from the folder rather than hard coding every file. Try:

```
import os #this is a handy module with operating system functions

def getMusic(place): #where place is the name of the folder in this case "Audio/". Don't forget the slash!
    for file in os.listdir(place): #os.listdir returns a list of all the files in a directory. 
        pygame.mixer.music.load(place+file)
```

Comment: Eh, that's what his first example did -- the one that didn't work.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, I'm not using os.path.join. I don't see the need for that.

Comment: The code that is at the bottom is not a solution to his problem, just a way to make his code more dynamic. The top part is what I think the solution to his problem is.

Comment: os.path.join works perfectly fine, avoids silly concatenation mistakes, and in this case generates the same filename (as you can tell from the error message).  Please don't spread misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

Paths are relative to the current directory, which isn't necessarily the same thing as the directory your script or module is in.  To check what it is, add:

```
print os.getcwd()
```

To compute paths relative to a module directory, you can do something like this:

```
module_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(module_directory, 'Audio', 'town3.midi')
```

(`__file__` gives you the module's filename, and `os.path.dirname` strips off the file part)

A simple helper function might be useful:

```
def load(midi_file):
    filename = os.path.join(module_directory, 'Audio', midi_file)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(filename)

load('town1.midi')
load('town2.midi')
load('town3.midi')
```

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I tried this, but it raises another pygame.error "Couldn't open 'C:\Users]Nick]Desktop\Vincible\Audio\title.midi'.  I'll post the new, revised code at the top for reference.

Comment: Is that ] in the path?  Looks weird.  Can you try adding a `print(os.getcwd())` statement before you set up pygame?

Comment: Printhing os.getcwd() returns "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Vincible"  As I said earlier, the files are in "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Vincible\Audio" (throwing it out there for reference)